# How to trigger a desktop notification for activity/silence on an MSYS2 terminal?

Tags: msys2

On KDE Konsole I can click a menu item to monitor terminal activity/silence. Konsole beeps and pops up a notification on the KDE desktop. Do you know of a package, script, terminal, or hack I can use to get MSYS2 to do the same on Windows?

There is nothing like that on mintty.

Thanks.